# Respected or respectable

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

What is correct ? "Respected family" or "respectable family".

When the sentence is -

> "My mother comes from a (respect) family.

Is that correct -

> Respected is only used before living being ,not before non-living thing like family or institution.

Answer (score 4):

A [respectable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respectable) family is one that is and does all the things that make it possible to respect them. It doesn't mean that anybody actually respects them, though. This could happen if, despite having a high social standing, living in a good area and doing everything that a respectable family should do, they are simply not very nice people. So, they are respectable, but not respected.

A [respected](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/respected) family is one that people actually do respect: either because they are respectable, or for other reasons. For example a family that has always lived on the wrong side of the tracks might become respected if one of their children is successful in a major sporting event. The family is respected but not respectable.